# Create "theme" for custom Android view containing multiple inner text views

Tags: android, android-view, android-styles

I have a custom view "address_view.xml" which displays a person's name and street address defined as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="John Smith"/>

    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/street_address"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:maxLines="2"
            tools:text="1 Main St."/>
</LinearLayout>
```

This view is used in multiple pages of my app, but there are 2 variations of font, text color, and size for each of the TextViews.

Is it possible to create "themes" for just this view, that set the textFont/textColor of the name and address TextViews separately? For example, I would like to do something like:

```
<com.example.view.AddressView
    ...
    style="@style/Theme1" />
```

which sets the "name" TextView to use FontA, ColorA, and Size1, and sets the "address" TextView to use FontB, ColorB, and Size2.

This way, I can use Theme1 on some pages and create another "Theme2" with the second combination of font/color/size and use it on the other pages.

Answer (score 1):

You first need to define custom attributes and then use them in a style. As an example I will use the styling a triangle.

First define what you want to be changing with your attributes and put them into `/res/attrs.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <declare-styleable name="Triangle">
        <attr name="triangleColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="triangleStrokeColor" format="color"/>
        <attr name="triangleStrokeWidth" format="dimension"/>
    </declare-styleable>
</resources>
```

And in your custom view you need to read the values you passed in

```
 // Get the values from XML
TypedArray typedArray = getContext().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, R.styleable.Triangle, style, 0);

int tmp;

mTriangleColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.Triangle_triangleColor, mTriangleColor);
mStrokeColor = typedArray.getColor(R.styleable.Triangle_triangleStrokeColor, mStrokeColor);

tmp = typedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(R.styleable.Triangle_triangleStrokeWidth, -1);
mStrokeWidth = tmp != -1 ? tmp : 2 * density; // Use 2dp as a default value

// Don't forget this!
typedArray.recycle();
```

And then define the styles. **NOTE:** there is no xml namespaces required for custom attribute items so there is no **android:**

```
<style name="defaultTriangle">
    <item name="triangleColor">#FF33B5E5</item>
    <item name="triangleStrokeColor">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="triangleStrokeWidth">3dp</item>
</style>
```

And then just apply

```
<some.package.Triangle
    style="@style/defaultTriangle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:rotation="0"
    />
```

Comment: How would this work for text fonts? My fonts are included as separate .ttf files in the assets/ folder.

Comment: You make an attribute of type string and then provide the location of fonts as a string. In your view you read that path and use it